# PhpStorm 2016.3 - JS syntax highlight colors not same in .php and .js files

Tags: javascript, ide, phpstorm

So, the question is as the title reads. 
I would greatly appreciate any help in understanding why could PhpStorm use different syntax highlighting colors in a .js file and .php file for JavaScript.

Contrary to the popular question of why js syntax highlighting doesn't work in .php files :)

I imported settings from PhpStorm 10 to 2016.3, but as I recall, version 10 had the same problem for me.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

As you can see, variable identifiers, function declaration, function calls, and other stuff is not highlighted correctly in the .js file, but looks just fine under `<script>` tags in .php files.

Here is a screenshot of Editor - Colors & Fonts - JavaScript:

[image]

According to this, everything is fine. But not in my .js files, where the bulk of work is :(

Comment: First screenshot, top right corner, it looks like code inspection/highlighting is off.

Comment: Wow, what the heck :D Thank you! Problem solved! Stackoverflow <3

Comment: @JuanTonina any ideas how to set code inspection/highlighting to top level by default for .js files? For now i have to manually turn it on for each new .js file.  No such problem with .php files.

Comment: make sure that your .js files are not located in excluded directory - inspections and highlighting are off for such files

Comment: @lena they are definitely not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out, as Juan Tonina suggested in the comment to my question, code inspection/highlighting was off for .js files for some reason. Big thanks!